# R: subsetting data to create three new subsets- using subset(), function or if/then conditional

Tags: r, filter, subset

I have been trying to subset data in a more nuanced way, to avoid excessive verbosity and redundancies. I find that I end up typing complicated conditions for subsetting, a method that is not feasible if I want to create multiple subsets of a dataframe.

Data:

```
> print(assm)
Speaker V1 POA V2
1     JF01  u  tt  U
2     JF01  o   r  a
3     JF01  o   t  a
4     JF01  a   r  u
5     JF01  e   l  i
6     JF01  a   j  o
7     JF01  e   s  o
8     JF01  u   l  i
9     JF01  a   j  i
10    JF01  i   y  a
11    JF01  o   g  i
12    JF01  u   m  O
13    JF01  u   l  E
14    JF01  a   t  o
15    JF01  o   r  u
16    JF01  a   l  e
17    JF01  u  tt  o
18    JF01  o   r  a
19    JF01  o   t  a
20    JF01  a   r  u
21    JF01  e   l  i
22    JF01  i   y  O
23    JF01  o   r  i
24    JF01  i   l  E
25    JF01  u   k  o
26    JF01  o   n  e
27    JF01  a   t  o
28    JF01  o   r  u
29    JF01  o   r  a
30    JF01  u   m  u
31    JF01  u   l  a
32    JF01  a   t  u
33    JF01  u  tt  o
34    JF01  o   r  a
35    JF01  o   t  a
36    JF01  a   h  e
37    JF01  u   r  e
38    JF01  o   l  i
39    JF01  i   b  o
40    JF01  o   l  e
41    JF01  e   j  u
42    JF01  a   l  e
43    JF01  u  tt  i
44    JF01  o   t  a
45    JF01  a   r  u
46    JF01  e   l  i
47    JF01  i   y  U
48    JF01  o   r  i
49    JF01  i   l  e
50    JF01  u   k  o
```

I used subset() and data[] to create 3 subsets with the following conditions:

```
assm <- subset(assm, V1==“a"| V1=="e"| V1=="E"| V1=="i"| V1=="o"| V1=="O"| V1=="u"| V1=="U", select = Speaker:V2)
assm <- subset(assm, V2==“a”| V2==“e”| V2=="E"| V2=="i"| V2=="o"| V2=="O"| V2=="u"| V2=="U", select = Speaker:V2)
```

**Is there a more efficient way(using regex for subsetting, for example) to avoid all the hard-coding(like using a variable)? The subsetting condition for V1 and V2 are identical, but I ended up typing things out two times.**

Using very rudimentary R, this is some more subsetting I did:

```
assm_h <- subset(assm, (V1=="o" & V2=="i")|
                     (V1=="e" & V2=="i")|
                     (V1=="u" & V2=="i")|
                     (V1=="e" & V2=="u")|
                     (V1=="o" & V2=="u")|
                     (V1=="u" & V2=="u"))

assm_nh <- subset(assm, (V1=="i" & V2=="O")|
                      (V1=="i" & V2=="E")|
                      (V1=="i" & V2=="U")|
                      (V1=="u" & V2=="O")|
                      (V1=="u" & V2=="E")|
                      (V1==“u" & V2=="U"))
```

I need one more subset(assm_neu), one that contains rows that do not match the conditions that subsets assm_h and assm_nh satisfy(i.e. the rest of the data), a task that requires even more painstaking coding. My method requires painstaking typing and multiple steps.

**Is there a way to make this task more efficient, so that the subsetting returns not just what is asked, but also returns a subset of the data that does not satisfy the conditions? I have read multiple posts about functions and conditionals, but none that would help me extract and create more than one dataset with a single command?**

Thanks in advance.
[edit: grammar]

Comment: *"more efficient way"*, such as `v<-c("a","e","E","i","o","O","u","U");subset(assm, V1%in%v & V2%in%v, select=Speaker:V2)`? or `subset(assm,grepl("[aeiouAEIOU]",V1)&grepl("[aeiouAEIOU]",V2),...)`?

Comment: BTW: `print` is doing very little for you, `assm` (without `print(..`) would invoke the default print method. Also, it is much easier to help you if you provide data that is more-easily consumed/copied, such as the output from `dput(head(assm,n=20))`.

Comment: It seems that GREP generally filters out the vowels, rather than the vowel pairs I am trying to subset.

Comment: thank you. This solves the first part of the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what level of flexibility you are trying to get, but here is how I would do your two additional subsetting cases:

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
```

First I read in your data as a `tibble` data frame:

```
> df <- as.tibble(read.table("temp.txt",header=TRUE))
```

Set combinations of `V1` and `V2` we are looking for:

```
combos <- c("oi","ei","ui","eu","ou","uu")
```

Now go make a temporary variable `V1V2`:

```
> df %>% mutate(V1V2=paste0(V1,V2))
# A tibble: 50 x 6
       x Speaker V1    POA   V2    V1V2 
   <int> <fct>   <fct> <fct> <fct> <chr>
 1     1 JF01    u     tt    U     uU   
 2     2 JF01    o     r     a     oa   
 3     3 JF01    o     t     a     oa   
 4     4 JF01    a     r     u     au   
 5     5 JF01    e     l     i     ei   
 6     6 JF01    a     j     o     ao   
 7     7 JF01    e     s     o     eo   
 8     8 JF01    u     l     i     ui   
 9     9 JF01    a     j     i     ai   
10    10 JF01    i     y     a     ia   
# ... with 40 more rows
```

And go find rows that meet that conditions (only 13 of them):

```
> df[z$V1V2 %in% combos,]
# A tibble: 13 x 5
       x Speaker V1    POA   V2   
   <int> <fct>   <fct> <fct> <fct>
 1     5 JF01    e     l     i    
 2     8 JF01    u     l     i    
 3    11 JF01    o     g     i    
 4    15 JF01    o     r     u    
 5    21 JF01    e     l     i    
 6    23 JF01    o     r     i    
 7    28 JF01    o     r     u    
 8    30 JF01    u     m     u    
 9    38 JF01    o     l     i    
10    41 JF01    e     j     u    
11    43 JF01    u     tt    i    
12    46 JF01    e     l     i    
13    48 JF01    o     r     i
```

If you want to find the rows that do not meet those condition (37 of them), then:

```
> '%ni%' <- Negate('%in%')
> df[!(z$V1V2 %ni% combos),]
# A tibble: 37 x 5
       x Speaker V1    POA   V2   
   <int> <fct>   <fct> <fct> <fct>
 1     1 JF01    u     tt    U    
 2     2 JF01    o     r     a    
 3     3 JF01    o     t     a    
 4     4 JF01    a     r     u    
 5     6 JF01    a     j     o    
 6     7 JF01    e     s     o    
 7     9 JF01    a     j     i    
 8    10 JF01    i     y     a    
 9    12 JF01    u     m     O    
10    13 JF01    u     l     E    
# ... with 27 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `split` to build a list of data frames encompassing all combinations of *V1* and *V2*. Then, subset the list by names for data frame subsets with a `do.call` to append all together:

```
df_list <- split(assm, assm[c("V1", "V2")])
names(df_list)
# [1] "a.a" "e.a" "i.a" "o.a" "u.a" "a.e" "e.e" "i.e" "o.e" "u.e" "a.E" "e.E" "i.E" "o.E" "u.E" "a.i" "e.i" "i.i" "o.i"
# [20] "u.i" "a.o" "e.o" "i.o" "o.o" "u.o" "a.O" "e.O" "i.O" "o.O" "u.O" "a.u" "e.u" "i.u" "o.u" "u.u" "a.U" "e.U" "i.U"
# [39] "o.U" "u.U"

# CONDITION VECTORS
cond_1 <- c("o.i", "e.i", "u.i", "e.u", "o.u", "u.u")
cond_2 <- c("i.O", "i.E", "i.U", "u.O", "u.E", "u.U")

# FIRST SUBSET
assm_h2 <- do.call(rbind, unname(df_list[cond_1]))
assm_h2 <- with(assm_h2, assm_h2[order(V1, V2),])

# SECOND SUBSET
assm_nh2 <- do.call(rbind, unname(df_list[cond_2]))
assm_nh2 <- with(assm_nh2, assm_nh2[order(V1, V2),])

# THIRD SUBSET (NOT IN EITHER LIST ABOVE)
assm_neu <- do.call(rbind, unname(df_list[!(names(df_list) %in% c(cond_1, cond_2))]))
```

As a test, first two above are equivalent to OP's originals after re-ordering *V1* and *V2* columns:

```
assm_h <- subset(assm, (V1=="o" & V2=="i")|
                   (V1=="e" & V2=="i")|
                   (V1=="u" & V2=="i")|
                   (V1=="e" & V2=="u")|
                   (V1=="o" & V2=="u")|
                   (V1=="u" & V2=="u"))

assm_h <- with(assm_h, assm_h[order(V1, V2),])

identical(assm_h, assm_h2)
# [1] TRUE

assm_nh <- subset(assm, (V1=="i" & V2=="O")|
                    (V1=="i" & V2=="E")|
                    (V1=="i" & V2=="U")|
                    (V1=="u" & V2=="O")|
                    (V1=="u" & V2=="E")|
                    (V1=="u" & V2=="U"))

assm_nh <- with(assm_nh, assm_nh[order(V1, V2),])

identical(assm_nh, assm_nh2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Is this a method that will work if one is working on large data sets?

Comment: this is a good method, but I am still typing out all three conditions. Is there a way to, say, define a variable(or variables) to input information in `df_list[c()]`    , so that one doesn’t have to type out the third condition(rbind all rows that don’t meet condition 1 or 2)?

Comment: You can save the vectors of conditions. See update and call according to subset. This is even less writing (only first 2 conditions) than your proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

r2evans rightly pointed out that GREP is the easiest way to subset the data. Thank you @mysteRious for suggesting a temporary column V1V2. I realised that there is a way to do this without a temporary column.

Here is a thought:

```
    attach(assm)
assm_h <- assm[grepl("^oi$|^ei$|^ui$|^eu$|^ou$|^uu$",(paste(assm$V1,assm$V2, sep=""))), ]
assm_nh <- assm[grepl("^iO$|^iE$|^iU$|^uO$|^uE$|^uU$",(paste(assm$V1,assm$V2, sep=""))), ]
assm_neu <- assm[!(grepl("^oi$|^ei$|^ui$|^eu$|^ou$|^uu$",(paste(assm$V1,assm$V2, sep=""))) | (grepl("^iO$|^iE$|^iU$|^uO$|^uE$|^uU$",(paste(assm$V1,assm$V2, sep=""))))), ]
```

The third case, logically, is a NOR condition: rows that satisfy neither condition not both conditions need to be selected.